# JQuery PreventDefault and IE8 clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, preventdefault

I have been trying to understand why sometimes IE8 doesn't like PreventDefault and why sometimes it seems to be OK (no errors). From what I have read, including here at SO is that events in jquery are normalised so preventDefault will always exist with a jQuery event. However regular javascript event bindings is when the following workaround is needed for ie8:

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false
```

Is this correct?

So if you are using jQuery .click .bind .on etc to handle an event then PreventDefault will not cause errors in IE8, such as:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    //no need for e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false as jquery event?
    //code
});
```

However if it is a regular Javascript event, such onclick then the workaround is needed?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds about right

Comment: The `e` parameter in a jQuery event handler is not the native event object, but rather an object created by jQuery. And the `.preventDefault` on jQuery's event object is not the native `.preventDefault`, but rather is a wrapper for something like your first example.

Comment: And FYI, if you're not supporting IE7 and lower, you can patch the `.preventDefault()` method into `Event.prototype` if it's missing.

Comment: @cookie-monster Does it have to be 'e'? if I used the word 'event' rather than just 'e' as the parameter would the same be true? I'm guessing yes, but just want to be sure, as I see most people use 'e' and wondered if it was for that reason, or just for simplicity sake.

Comment: @Martin: You can name parameters whatever valid identifier you want. `e` is just less typing than `event`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, just wanted to be sure. :) as e seems to be the choice of most.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding sounds correct. Also, if you're using a "DOM0" event handler (e.g. `someElement.onclick = function(e) { ... }`), there is a simpler way to prevent the browser default behaviour that works in all browsers that support events: `return false`.

```
var someElement = document.getElementById("someElementId");
someElement.onclick = function(e) {
    // Do some stuff
    return false;
};
```

However, in this case, the event is not passed to the event handler in IE <= 8 and you have to get it from `window.event` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Tim , not sure why somebody down voted your answer. It wasn't me, my reputation points (lack of) don't allow me to up or down vote an answer!

Comment: @Martin: Don't worry, the occasional downvote doesn't bother me anyway. I imagine someone took exception to the mere mention of using DOM0 event handlers.