# Chrome ignoring jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have the following html/code that works fine in IE but when I click the link in Chrome, nothing happens.
   The HTML is as follows:

```
<h1 id="pagetitle">Daina - kora dziesmu kr&#257jums</h1>
<div class="frontpage">
<p id="arvilcinu"><a href="">Ar vilci&#326u R&#299ga braucu</a></p>
</div>
<!--***************** Ar Vilcinu *******************-->
<div id="arvilcinudisplay" class="singlesong">
<p><a href="Ar vilcinu riga braucu.pdf">Click here to download PDF file for printing</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuRxjjEaJVQ" target="_blank">Click here to watch the video - sung by Daina</a></p>
<p id="back"><a href=""><img src="backbutton.jpg" alt="Back to Main menu" height="40" width="100"></a></p>
</div>
```

The jquery bit of script is as follows:

```
$("#arvilcinu").click(function(){
    $(".frontpage").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        document.getElementById("pagetitle").innerHTML = "Ar vilci&#326u R&#299ga braucu";
        $("#arvilcinudisplay").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

The idea is that when the user clicks the link (id=arvilcinu) that the link fades out and the relevant info is then displayed. Clicking the link in Chrome just makes the screen flash for a second but nothing on the screen changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `preventDefault()` to remove natural behaviour of link and to fire click event written by you, like below :

Also you can write your code in jQuery only (no javascript) --

```
$("#arvilcinu").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $(".frontpage").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $("#pagetitle").html("Ar vilci&#326u R&#299ga braucu");
        $("#arvilcinudisplay").show();
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/311/)

Comment: Thanks heaps - works a treat! So why does this work in IE but not Chrome? Is there any way that I can set this by default so I dont have to call preventDefault for all my links?

Comment: I am not sure why it is working in IE. But I just tried your code in JSFiddle and figure out the problem. for more information see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: I will update you once i get the reason behind it :)

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033728/jquery-preventdefault-and-ie8-clarification

Comment: Thanks for your kind responses. Its probably got something to do with the fact that my href is blank so Im really just "simulating" a link. The version of Ie its working in is IE8 btw...

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the two event will be occur when you click on the link. one is of your anchor tag `<a href="" >...` and another is of your click event on element whose id is `arvilcinu`. anchor tag is inside of the `<p id="arvilcinu">` which leads to this behaviour.
You need to prevent default behaviour of the `<a>` tag which will be done by using
[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function on the event.

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

You code should look like below :

```
$("#arvilcinu").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // rest of you logic on click event
});
```